# Transferring data from controller to view - List<> / IEnumerable<>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm building an asp.net MVC application using the Entity Framework, but it's not working the way I want it to.

This is my model (not all model classes, but that's not relevant):

```
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        Categories = new List<Category>();
    }

    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public Offer Offer { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        Products = new List<Product>();
    }

    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

What I am building now is a page to show all products in a specific category. So if you go to, let's say, /Category/1 it should show all products in category 1. Currently I am doing it this way.
In the controller I have this method:

```
public ActionResult Category(int ID)
{
    return View(db.Categories.Where(c => c.CategoryID == ID).Include(c => c.Products));
}
```

which should load all products of that specific category and send that data to the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Webshop.Models.Product>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Category: " + @ViewBag.CategoryName;
}

<h2>@ViewBag.CategoryName</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().Name)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().Price)</th>
        <th>Details</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var product in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@product.Name</td>
            <td>@product.Price</td>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Product", new { ID = product.ProductID })</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

This should work, right? Well it's not.
If I go to /Category/1 I get the following error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[Webshop.Models.Category]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Webshop.Models.Product]'.

Adding `.ToList()` in the controller doesn't work.

Actually it makes sense, but I don't know any other way to do this. And what is even weirder is that I followed an asp.net tutorial from Microsoft where they did exactly this.

I hope anyone can help me figure this out.

Comment: Are you sure `db.Categories.Where(c => c.CategoryID == ID).Include(c => c.Products)` returns a not empty list of Products?

Comment: Your query returns `IEnumerable<Category>` but you view accepts `<IEnumerable<Product>`. What do you actually want to display (one category and all its products or all categories and all their products)?

Comment: @JúlioMurta Apparently you're right. It wasn't returning any Product.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I want to display all products in one category. But apparently the query was just wrong. (And the complicated way I was using ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view is expecting a model of `IEnumerable<Webshop.Models.Product>`, but your controller method is returning a collection of `Category` objects.

I'd change your view to this:

```
@model Webshop.Models.Category

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Category: " + Model.Name;
}

<h2>@ViewBag.CategoryName</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products.FirstOrDefault().Name)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products.FirstOrDefault().Price)</th>
        <th>Details</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var product in Model.Products)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@product.Name</td>
            <td>@product.Price</td>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Product", new { ID = product.ProductID })</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Then your controller method becomes this:

```
public ActionResult Category(int ID)
{
    return View(db.Categories.Where(c => c.CategoryID == ID).Include(c => c.Products).FirstOrDefault());
}
```

You'd probably want to do some check to make sure the category was found instead of returning a null Category as this will do if the given `ID` isn't found.

Comment: This was the first time that I used LINQ, I think that's why the query was wrong. This is indeed a way better solution. Yeah, I need to built some error-checks. For example redirecting to a page that shows a list of all categories (I first need to find out how to do it). Is it best to check if ID is null or is it a better approach to first execute the query and check the amount returned?